# less < operator not recognize if I set like string PHP

Tags: php, operators

I have strange problem with `PHP`. When I set the string like '<' and if I make new string with few strings then when is go to '<' is stop to working and go to next row of the script

```
$a = new SomeObject();
$a->where('id', 13332, "<");

public function where($column, $param, $operator = '=') {
    echo strlen($operator);
    if (isset($column) && strlen($operator) > 0) {
        echo $operator;
        if ($operator === '>') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '>?';
        } else if ($operator == '<') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '<?';
        } else if ($operator === '=') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '=?';
        } else {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . $operator . '?';
        }
        $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . chr(0x3c) . '?';
        echo '<br/>' . $this->_where . '<br/>';
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('We need to have $column variable like string and $param like Param!', 500);
    }
    echo '<br/>c';
}
```

> And the result is:
>
> 1< WHERE id c

And my question is why less `<` is cannot get like string. The `>` and `=` operators is OK. But the `<` just is not recognize. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense. What do you mean `<` isn't recognised? What are you expecting?

Comment: I expecting when put this symbol '<' then in _where string to get this  '<' symbol. In my case is just stop to this line

Comment: only spaces is required like:-  `'> ?'` and `'< ?'` and `'= ?'`

Comment: Thanks Anant now is ok

Comment: @Anant of course. Just need one more minute

Comment: @RiggsFolly  is completly correct here

Comment: Wait, what? What has the space got to do with anything? There's nothing wrong with `<?` inside a single quote string when you're already within PHP unless I've been mistaken for a long time...

Comment: Case and point https://3v4l.org/vCO5Z

Comment: As @JonStirling said: `'<?'` is a text not a short tag for `<?php`. This is short tag `<?`. This is text `'<?'`

Comment: Apologise for confusing everyone. Your code (minus some of the debug lines) works just fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove one line and it will work (test one below yourself):-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); //check all type of errors
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those if any happen

$a = new SomeObject();
$a->where('id', 13332, "<");

public function where($column, $param, $operator = '=') {
    echo strlen($operator);
    if (isset($column) && strlen($operator) > 0) {
        echo $operator;
        if ($operator === '>') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '> ?'; // added space
        } else if ($operator == '<') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '< ?'; // added space
        } else if ($operator === '=') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '= ?'; // added space
        } else {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . $operator . '?';
        }
        //$this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . chr(0x3c) . '?';  remove this line
        echo '<br/>' . $this->_where . '<br/>';
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('We need to have $column variable like string and $param like Param!', 500);
    }
    echo '<br/>c';
}
```

Note:-

Reason for not working:-

You have to add  spaces too to make it correct(commented by @RiggsFolly) (For browser showing sake)

You are just over-writing your conditions. (commented and example by @JonStirling :- https://3v4l.org/vCO5Z) (for working purpose)

Comment: @JonStirling It was intended as such. But in my defence, what was happening was of course when you `echo '1<<br/> WHERE id<?<br/><br/>c';` **in a browser** the `<?` completely disappears

Comment: @Anant This is purely down to trying to display the result badly in a browser

Comment: Completely understandable where the confusion came from and apologies are complete unnecessary, especially if they're being aimed in my general direction. Now +1'd :D

Comment: I assume `<?` wont show in a browser as it assumes its a badly formed html tag and it is trying to compensate for our mistakes

Comment: @RiggsFolly  thanks. Now if you and others want we can remove comment. up-to-you guys

Comment: Hmm! I would love to know definitively why that disappears then

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
$this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . chr(0x3e) . '?';
```

you overwrite your all previous changes so no wonder you can not see right result

Comment: I tested like that and again is not working. And this is for > not for < the code is chr(0x3c)

Comment: only spaces is required like:- `'> ?'` and `'< ?' `and `'= ?'`

Comment: This is not actually the issue. That overwrite is actually the exactly duplicate of what woudl have been generated in the `if <?`. Its purely an issue of displaying `<?` in a browser which is not displayed, where `< ?` will be displayed

Comment: Yes, now I can agree. <? may cause problems in browser but not in php as you mentioned before :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this function and let me know will it gives you desired output

```
public function where($column, $param, $operator = '=') {
    echo strlen($operator);
    if (isset($column) && strlen($operator) > 0) {
        echo $operator;
        if ($operator === '>') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '> ?';
        } else if ($operator == '<') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '< ?';
        } else if ($operator === '=') {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . '= ?';
        } else {
            $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . $operator . ' ?';
        }
        if($this->_where != '')
        {
            $this->_where .= ' and ' . $column . chr(0x3e) . ' ?';
        }
        else
        {
          $this->_where = ' WHERE ' . $column . chr(0x3e) . ' ?';
        }
        echo '<br/>' . $this->_where . '<br/>';
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('We need to have $column variable like string and $param like Param!', 500);
    }
    echo '<br/>c';
}
```

Comment: only spaces is required like:- `'> ?'` and `'< ?' `and `'= ?'`